# open file from Cloud9's terminal (bash) in its IDE

Tags: bash, text-editors, ide, aws-cloud9

What command would open a file in the default editor of Cloud9's IDE from within its own terminal bash shell?

I tried `xdg-open` and `gnome-open` but those opens in emacs.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Cloud 9 CLI docs and help, you should be able to open file in the Cloud 9 IDE with this:

```
c9 open <filename>
```

However, it currently returns an error message. As indicated by [this issue](https://github.com/c9/c9.ide.installer/issues/2), this function appears to be broken on the hosted VMs (eg: running on ide.c9.io).